# How to configure cucumber and selenium in eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I want to work with cucumber and selenium by using eclipse IDE, but I need help, how can I set up maven project and whats are the dependencies should be added in pom.xml file, please provide me steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have following guidelines -

1. Make sure `maven` in installed in your eclipse if not then first you need to do that
2. Now create a simple Maven project and after success, edit the `pom.xml` file and add following dependencies under `<project>` tag -

   ```
    <dependencies>
           <dependency> 
              <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
              <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
              <version>2.53.1</version> 
           </dependency>

           <dependency> 
              <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
              <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId> 
              <version>1.0.2</version> 
              <scope>test</scope> 
           </dependency>

               <dependency> 
                  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
                  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
                  <version>1.0.2</version> 
                  <scope>test</scope> 
               </dependency>

           <dependency> 
              <groupId>junit</groupId> 
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
              <version>4.10</version> 
              <scope>test</scope> 
           </dependency>  
     </dependencies>
   ```

Once you are going to save the xml, it will downloaded all mentioned dependency jar files.

3. Now create your cucumber test (feature file and step definition file) under `src/test/java`

For detailed description and learning refer [cucumber tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/index.htm) link.